# Copy and paste unique files from a folder to different computers on network

Tags: java, batch-file, copy, paste

I could have done this twice now in the time that I have looked at how to do it, but I want to figure this out and have something I can potentially use later on. We have departments with a standard naming scheme, so this would come in handy down the road if one department needs a file or shortcut I could simply iterate through that department's computer numbers.

I am trying to copy RDP sessions to appropriate computers.  The biggest caveat is I have '01' and not just '1' to change the integer and cast it to a string.

The computer naming scheme is DPTNN (ex: HR01, HR02, HR03).
The RDP shortcuts are similar DPTNN.rdp (ex: HR01.rdp, HR02.rdp, HR03.rdp)

Here's my disgusting pseudo Java/batch code...

`int i = 1;
 while i <= 13{
  copy \\\\SERVER\c$\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Folder\RDPSESSION+'i' \\CLIENTPC+'i'+D\\c$\users\USERNAME\desktop
i++;
}`

Comment: Not understanding what this has to do with batch-files?

Comment: @Squashman this could easily be a batch file

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried formatting your variable?

Example in bash:

```
$ i=2
$ printf "%.2d\n" $i
02
```